# Call a controller method in a view using onclick option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have the following problem. I would like to call a controller method which executes some sql statements by onklick option of a button or a link.

So I got a method "publish" in my controller. It looks sth like this:

```
def publish
  do execute sql statements
  flash[:notice] = 'sql statements executed.'
end
```

And in my view I would like to have a button or a link to call this method like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="<% controller.publish %>">
```

But I get the error:

> undefined local variable or method

I also tried to route it to use this method as :action. That did not work as well. I searched now for a while and found some solutions by making this method a helper_method, though I get the same error again.
I'm pretty new to Ruby and Rails so I hope you can help me.

Comment: Do you want it to call the method and redirect or do it via AJAX?

Comment: I want to call the method and redirect to the same page I am on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in your view, you try something like `<% controller.publish %>`, that will call the `publish` action *when the view is rendered*, not when a user clicks on the button.

You can do something like this:

1. Create a route which will invoke `publish` when requested. For example, say the route is `/publish`.
2. In your view, put something like this:

`<input type="button" onclick="window.location = '/publish'">`

The value of the `onclick` attribute must be valid JavaScript, which will be executed when the  button is clicked. In JS, setting `window.location` causes the browser to navigate to a different page. In this case, we are making the browser navigate to `/publish`, which will cause your `publish` action to be invoked. Whatever you render in `publish` will then appear in the browser.

In the code for `publish` which you show above, your Ruby syntax is wrong, but I am assuming that it is just a sample, not the actual code which you are using.

Comment: I created a route now like this:
post "/publish" => redirect("/wiki")

But it still tries to reach to url/publish and there is no such page. How can I use my method and still stay on the same page I am.

Comment: Your route isn't working because it only matches POST requests. You need to accept GET requests for `/publish`.

Answer (score 1):

Your ruby on rails code is server side.
The code in your view e.g `<input type="button" onclick="<% controller.publish %>">`
is client side.

You can't call server side methods directly from client side code, since the client code is just running in the user's browser.
I've not used RoR so don't know the details but you will have to submit a message to the server from the client side code, at the server side you will then want to receive this and call the publish method from there.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, if your SQL statements are going to change any data (which it looks like they are meant to), it's important that you use a POST request and not a GET request. To do that, you either need to use a basic form submission instead of clicking on a link, OR use javascript to submit the POST request when clicking on the link. Let's talk about the second way since that will stay consistent with how you want the app to look.

Assuming jQuery, you can use the [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method to post to your `publish` action when the button is clicked. In the success callback, you can display the message about the sql statements having been executed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What would the jQuery.post method look like when I don't want to change the page on submitting the POST request? Can I just skip the [url] then?

Comment: No, you would provide the url, say /publish. In the controller, after doing the sql updates, just finish it with 'head :ok' which will return a 200 response to the browser, and the user will stay on the same page. The 200 response will make the success callback get called, in which you can display a "It worked!" sort of message on the page.

Answer (score 0):

@alex-d's answer seems to be enough. Just use `button_to` and at the end of your `publish` action you can redirect to the same page (or the same action as before, if you're loading records to show in the view).

**EDIT:** From @alex-d's answer:

> Create a route which will invoke publish when requested. For example, say the route is /publish.

```
GET '/publish' to: 'Controller#publish'
```

> In your view, put something like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location = '/publish'">
```

Now on your controller method, redirect:

```
def publish
  do execute sql statements
  flash[:notice] = 'sql statements executed.'
  redirect_to route_where_the_button_view_is_path #(or render if that controller method isnt necessary)
  return #to avoid multiple render or redirect error (maybe not necessary)
end
```

PD: My code may not work at the first try, I'm working this out from memory.

GL & HF.

Comment: Is there a possibility to create a route which will point to my controller method and then redirect to the page where the button is at?

Comment: @Arty, you need 2 things: a route and a controller method. Once you create a button that goes to said route (which goes to your controller method) you just need to redirect to wherever you want. I'll edit my answer for better format.

Comment: Yeah I understood what you mean and already tried it. Though I get the same error page not found as it tries to connect to /publish but there is no such page.

Comment: @Arty what is the route you're using?

Comment: This is the route I use {post "/publish", to: "aicwiki#publish"}

Comment: @Arty Use GET unless you require params from the button, which I guess you don't.