# Incrementing model integer via custom method and form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, methods, rails-routing

I'm extremely new to Rails and so I apologize if this is a simple question. I am attempting to build a simple site that allows users to vote as whether or not they liked the lunch that day.  Lunches are associated with providers (restaurants) and thus providers will have many different "lunches."

I know it is possible to auto increment by adding this to a method in the controller [(discussed more here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407069/call-a-controller-method-in-a-view-using-onclick-option) and my current setup looks like this:

The view:

```
<%-# Show current like and dislike counts. -%>
<div> Likes: <%= @lunch.liked %> </div>
<div> Dislikes: <%= @lunch.disliked %> </div>


<div>
    <%= form_for :lunch url: lunch_path, method: :put do |f| %>
      <div><%= f.hidden_field :disliked %></div>
      <div><%= f.hidden_field :id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Disike Lunch", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
  def downvote_lunch
    @lunch = Lunch.find(params[:id])
    @lunch.increment!(:disliked)
    redirect_to lunch_path
  end
```

Routes:

```
 resources :lunches
```

...

```
match '/dislike',      to: 'lunches#downvote_lunch',      via: 'get'
```

However, when I click on the "Dislike Button" it tells me that there is no view for "update" - I've defined update as an empty method in the controller, but I'm not sure why it's accessing update - all I'm looking for is to reload lunches/:id with the updated count for "disliked."

**My question**: How do I get the form to point to the custom "downvote_lunch" method, and have it redirect back to the lunches/:id after successfully incrementing the "dislikes" integer in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it you have to do

In view

```
 <div>
   <%= form_for :lunch url: downvote_lunch_lunch_path(params[:id]), method: :put do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :disliked %></div>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :id %></div>
   <%= f.submit "Disike Lunch", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In routes

```
 resources :lunches do
  member do
    put :downvote_lunch
  end
 end
```

In controller

```
  def downvote_lunch
    @lunch = Lunch.find(params[:id])
    @lunch.increment!(:disliked)
    redirect_to @lunch
  end
```

it will work as you want

Comment: This is great - it worked perfectly.  I guess the key here is I need to read more about member methods of a resource? I'll review [the rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to ensure I don't get stuck on this issue again.